# What is the reason for these error messages?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, rad

I'm getting error messages for no reason in RAD 8:

[image]

[image]

And the error message is complaining about a totally different method in a totaly different project in a totally different package. Is my error reporting erroneous? How can I resolve this? Since JSP validation appears to be broken in RAD 8 I have turned off validation for fragments but I want to be able to find legitimate errors. How do I proceed?

Comment: To exclude the one and other, do your "normal" Java classes compile without problems? A missing `String` type indicates that JRE is not properly configured in IDE's properties, but that would cause the entire codebase being uncompilable.

Comment: What is strange is that is compiles and I can redeploy a change to websphere. I can compile other classes with no problems and if I rearrange the code I can make the errors for a class go away but they shouldn't appear to begin with. I've joined a project with a lot of old code that doesn't totally adhere to conventions so there are a lot of errors and warnings that may be too many for the RAD to keep organized so if I can start and get the errors and warning down to less than what I have the validation could work better.

Comment: Okay, that's thus a RAD problem. I've worked with standard Eclipse for ages, currently using Indigo SR2, and never seen this. Only JSP EL validation goes sometimes havoc, but that's an acknowledged problem in Eclipse WTP and not related to what you're seeing with *scriptlets*. I'd test it in standard Eclipse for Java EE just to be sure and if it works fine, then I'd report an issue to RAD.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for the investigation. With JSPF validation turned off I still have 297 errors and 47678 warnings(!) from different projects that I have open that this project depends on. For a long time it seems that the developers didn't care about warnings and now at least I must get the errors down to a manageable level and when my number of errors and warnings are more normal then RAD can have a better change of performing my validation. I can still compile and work on the project, but it really needs cleaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is late, but...

When the error indicators don't even align with the source, it seems like RAD/Eclipse is internally looking at an outdated version of the file. I usually can clear this up by closing and re-opening the file, re-validating the file, or running a Clean build.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm still working to get this under control and reduce the number of problems in my project that has inherited a legacy framework which comes with tons of problems already and having a long list of problems in Eclipse might be a too long list so that the list of problems has gotten too long. There are also many legitimate warnings as well as these warnings and errors that appear for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be something new in WAS 8.  The validation is broken and must be turned off in order for this to work.  Found out while upgrading from 6.1->8.0.

Fragments?  Scriptlets?  You shouldn't have those in JSPs.  That's 1998 vintage stuff.  I'd recommend JSTL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not my scriptlet and it's an old project that I've been recruited to. There are tons and tons of errors and warnings and almost everything is done with scriptlets. I'm trying to reduce the number of warnings and errors so that I actually can see which errors and warnings are legitimate. I plan to rewrite the entire project with EL and JSTL instead of scriptlets but first the project management must agree to this.